# Create an indefinite number of data structures based on number of DOM elements retrieved with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to instantiate an indefinite number of javascript array, relying on the number of elements retrieved with jQuery.

```
dogHouse = {};
var dogs = $('.dogs'); // admit that dogs.length = 2
```

Now, I'd like to use each loop (or something else) to instantiate (in this case) two arrays definited in dogHouse or in window, each with his own name.

```
dogs.each( function(){

});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but it's really not clear what output you're trying to achieve. http://api.jquery.com/map should get you close though

Comment: re-phrase the question. Its not clear.

Comment: The answer to your question is **yes**.